# How to get Facebook logged-in user data on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement functionality so that I can get user data from Facebook. I have already implemented Facebook login functionality. is there any way to get current logged-in user data through the user Facebook login on my website?

Comment: The example under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web contains the basic form of this already, the `FB.api('/me', ...)` API call. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/